# is u(x,t) is a solution of the heat equation, then so is v

Tags: partial-differential-equations, invariance, heat-equation

Show that if $u(x,t)$ is a solution of the heat equation
\begin{equation*}
u_t - k u_{xx}  = 0 \,,\qquad (x\in R,\  t\geq0)\,,
\end{equation*}
then so is
\begin{equation*}
v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{kt}} \exp\left( \frac{ -x^2}{4kt} \right) \ u( \frac{x}{kt}, - \frac{1}{k^2t}) \,.
\end{equation*}

I am using Walter A. Strauss as text, and I try to follow "invariance properties", and I am trying to find a "dilated" function, but got confused on the negative sign before "$\frac{1}{k^2t}$" , I also referring to http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124A/lecs/lec9.pdf, but it seems not same, so I am not sure where to start, can someone help me with a hint, an example or a better resources?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just compute the appropriate derivatives of $v$ and verify that they satisfy the heat equation?

Comment: Is your question why $v$ solves the heat equation too or how to motivate the particular form of $v$? For the first, It seems that to calculate $v_t$ and $kv_{xx}$ would be a good starting point. You should use that $u$ is a solution to heat equation to estabilsh $v_t-kv_{xx}=0$. For the latter see http://www4.ncsu.edu/~shearer/heat_eqn.pdf

Comment: Hey @NateEldredge, although it should work, but I think we are supposed to derive v instead of verifying it is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I think we are supposed to derive $v$ instead of verifying it is a solution.

You are supposed to derive $v$ with the purpose of verifying it is a solution.

> I am trying to find a "dilated" function

You don't need to find any functions; you are given all the functions you need.

To get you started: the product and chain rule yield
$$ 
\begin{split}
v_x(x,t) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{kt}} \frac{-2x}{4kt} \exp\left( \frac{ -x^2}{4kt} \right) \ u\left( \frac{x}{kt}, - \frac{1}{k^2t}\right) \\  &+
\frac{1}{\sqrt{kt}}  \exp\left( \frac{ -x^2}{4kt} \right) \frac{1}{kt} \ u_x\left( \frac{x}{kt}, - \frac{1}{k^2t}\right)
\end{split}$$

Next, take $x$ derivative again to find $v_{xx}$. (It will be the sum of five terms, some of which will be equal.) Finally, find $v_t$ and check that $v_t=kv_{xx}$.

Comment: Hey, @user98130, thanks for reply, I finished calculating, just wonder when you take derivative of u(x/kt,−1/k^2*t) w.r.t t, do you consider t in x/kt? if I just ignore that and write Vx=(1/k^2*t^2)*Ux,then I can simplify it and if u(x/kt,−1/k^2*t) is a solution to the DE, I make it done. Further, this induce the question of "invariance property", that is, if u(x,t)is a solution, so does u(ax,a^2*t) with a>0,here we are using a=1/k^2*t^2, so I am wondering a can be more than a constant? Cause we have t in a and it seems when take derivative w.r.t t,we are treating t in x/kt as a constant.